# Android Webview load in background, show when ready

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity, background, webview

I'm working on an app which gets an intent from another app. When the intent is received the app have to execute some javascript for navigation to another page. After navigation the javascript gives an trigger that the app can execute in the foreground.

The problem is when I send an intent, the webview doesn't excist and the javascript function can't be called. So I have to call the onCreate function first before executing the javascript function.

The problem of calling the onCreate function is that the app starts and shows the webview, but I want to show it after loading the new page.

90% of all have to work in the background, but is this possible with loading data in an View object? Is there a way to call the onCreate function (by startActivity with Intent) and not show the app to the user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use onStart() and onResume() functions also, you are not contrained by putting everything in onCreate().

Please read the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: Thats right. But the problem is the app have to load the webview once to know the javascript and init the webview. Otherwise I get a nullPointerExeption on the webview.

Comment: Create the webview in onCreate(), load the url in onStart().  Do not ry to modify the webview with javascript, that's bad, real bad

Comment: Also now I'm curious why would you want to?  It sounds like you should just be navigating to another page inside the original webview without an intent, unless this is an android 3.0+ tablet thing, but then you would use fragments

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the app is totally working in Javascript. and have to do some actions in the background (like gather data and store it). Some data comes by an intent from another app on the phone. When new data is send it have to send it to the mobile webpage to do something with it. If it is needed the user gets an notification to open the app, or the app is send to the foreground (last thing is not permitted from android guidelines) 

Maybe I have an new idea to get it work. But I think the main problem is that the webview is an View(able) object